# If date = today -> check box checked

Tags: javascript, function, pouchdb

1. I have a form, when form is submitted all data goes to PouchDB.
2. Then I have to show a table with data from DB - 50 rows in the table.
3. If the date in the form = today - check box has to be checked.

Here's what I've tried:

```
function showTableOfVauchers(data) {
    var div = document.getElementById("table");
    var str = "<table aligh='left'><tr><th>#</th>"+"<th>VendorID</th><th>Amount</th><th>date</th><th>Invoice#</th><th>Fund</th><th>DeptID</th><th>Description</th></tr>";

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        str +=  "<tr><td>"+data[i].doc._id+
                "</td><td>"+data[i].doc.vendorID+
                "</td><td>"+data[i].doc.amount+
                "</td><td>"+data[i].doc.date+
                "</td><td>"+data[i].doc.invoiceNumber+           
                "</td><td>"+data[i].doc.fund+
                "</td><td>"+data[i].doc.deptID+
                "</td><td>"+data[i].doc.descript+
                "</td><td>"+ dateCheck(data[i].doc.date)+
                "</td></tr>"
    }
    str += "</table>";
    div.innerHTML = str;

    function dateCheck(date1){
        if (date1==today){
            return "<input type='checkbox' checked>"
        }
        else {
            return "<input type='checkbox'>"
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Check escape sequences - how to write `"` inside a string.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting in your posted code, it *shows* you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chek your syntax ,

```
if(date1 = today)
```

i guess it should be

```
if(date1==today)
```

check the string you are returning.

```
"<input type=\"checkbox\" checked>";
```

Comment: Could you take the time to explain *why*; that way the OP might learn something useful for the future.

Comment: hey i though so dat his condition might be wrong, Moreover i have changed the string he is returning which is what he wanted.

Comment: I wasn't criticising your answer, just asking you to explain it – for the benefit of the OP – in order that s/he can learn something good future development.

Comment: Yeah I understand, the "if" condition has nothing to do with the error, but i thought he might have just done it by mistake. I hope he got what he wanted now. :)

Comment: I've changed to if(date1==today) and changed 
"<input type="checkbox" checked>";  to "<input type='checkbox' checked>"

And it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Congrats!!! for now, but do a lil learning of how to add an html string in javascript which may contain dynamic values from javascript.